How to resolve Goose3 connection error 10054?
I run a script on daily basis using a cronjob and here we are using g.extract to extract articles and my script fails 2 out of 5 times with an error : Error occurred: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)). Retrying with a new User-Agent... 
Here is the code I am using with multiple user-agents and selecting a random user-agent every time:
for news_item in filtered_news:
    user_agents = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    ]
    for attempt in range(3):
        try:
            headers = {'User-Agent': random.choice(user_agents), 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/'}
            g = Goose({'browser_user_agent': headers['User-Agent'], 'strict': False})
            article = g.extract(url = news_item['url'])
        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ConnectionResetError) as e:
            print(f"Error occurred: {e}. Retrying with a new User-Agent...")
    print(news_item['url'])
    time.sleep(3)

But I keep getting the 10054 error

You are making the remote mad somehow. You make all 3 requests even when the first one succeeds. The remote may not like being pinged again so quickly. Or perhaps one of the agents isn't accepted. You could print agent and exit on the first successful extraction to test.
